# Stop ssh client from offering all the public keys it can find?

Tags: ssh, public-key, private-key

Like most sysadmins I use openssh all the time. I have about a dozen ssh keys, I like to have a different ssh key for each host. However this causes a problem when I am connecting to a host for the first time, and all I have is a password. I want to just connect to the host using a password, no ssh key in this case. However the ssh client will offer all the public keys in my `~/.ssh/` (I know this from looking at the output of `ssh -v`). Since I have so many, I will get disconnected for too many authentication failures.

Is there some way to tell my ssh client to not offer all the ssh keys?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This is expected behaviour according to the man page of `ssh_config`:

```
 IdentityFile
         Specifies a file from which the user's DSA, ECDSA or DSA authentica‐
         tion identity is read.  The default is ~/.ssh/identity for protocol
         version 1, and ~/.ssh/id_dsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa and ~/.ssh/id_rsa for
         protocol version 2.  Additionally, any identities represented by the
         authentication agent will be used for authentication.  

         [...]

         It is possible to have multiple identity files specified in configu‐
         ration files; all these identities will be tried in sequence.  Mul‐
         tiple IdentityFile directives will add to the list of identities
         tried (this behaviour differs from that of other configuration
         directives).
```

Basically, specifying `IdentityFile`s just adds keys to a current list the SSH agent already presented to the client.

Try overriding this behaviour with this at the bottom of your `.ssh/config` file:

```
Host *
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

You can also override this setting on the host level, e.g.:

```
Host foo
  User bar
  IdentityFile /path/to/key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Comment: You can also use `ssh -o "IdentitiesOnly true" -v -A user@host` which is what I use to login to a machine which has none of my keys but I want to offer agent-forwarding to go on. (`-v` for verbose debugging).

Comment: @eckes that's a nice tip, but shouldn't it be `yes` (and not `true`) though?

Comment: `IdentitiesOnly` may not always help, you may have to exclude a host specifically; see https://superuser.com/questions/859661/how-can-i-force-ssh-to-ignore-the-identityfile-listed-in-host-for-one-specif

Answer (score 56):

Although others have hinted at this with configuration-based solutions, it's probably worth pointing out that you can easily do this one-time-only on the command line with:

```
ssh -o 'PubkeyAuthentication no' myhostname.mydomain
```

Comment: Perfect .. THE solution IMHO

Comment: Correct this should have been the accepted answer.

Answer (score 14):

Following James Sneeringer's solution, you might just want to set an ssh_config along the lines of:

```
Host *.mycompany.com
  IdentityFile .ssh/id_dsa_mycompany_main

Host *.mycustomer.com
  IdentityFile .ssh/id_dsa_mycustomer

Host *
  RSAAuthentication no #this should be up top, avoid ssh1 at all costs
  PubkeyAuthentication no
```

If you connect with a particular key to many machines not in a common domain, consider giving them all CNAMEs in your own DNS.  I do this with all customer systems.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to user23413's solution, you can disable public key authentication altogether for a particular host (or wildcard pattern):

```
Host *.example.org
RSAAuthentication no        # SSHv1
PubkeyAuthentication no     # SSHv2
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an `IdentitiesOnly` option that you can set to `yes`, either with `-o IdentitiesOnly=yes` on the command line or `IdentitiesOnly yes` in `~/.ssh/config`.

From the `ssh_config(5)` man page:

```
 IdentitiesOnly
         Specifies that ssh(1) should only use the configured
         authentication identity and certificate files (either the default
         files, or those explicitly configured in the ssh_config files or
         passed on the ssh(1) command-line)
```

However! If you don’t have any `IdentifyFile` specified, either in
`~/.ssh/config` or with some `-i` option on the command line, then the default
identity files `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, `~/.ssh/id_ed25519` will still be used!

So if you really want ssh to use *only* explicitly specified keys, you also
need to specify some invalid `IdentifyFile`, e.g., `-i /dev/null`.

For example:

```
Host *.example.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.example.com

Host *.example.org
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.example.org

# Important! The `Host *` block must come **last**, because subsequent `Host`
# blocks cannot override any preceding `Host *` settings. See ssh_config(5):
# “For each parameter, the first obtained value will be used”
Host *
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityFile /dev/null
```

Answer (score -1):

If you point to a particular key file with ssh -i /path/to/key it'll only use that one even if others are loaded into the agent, and you won't be prompted for the password.  You can also edit you ~/.ssh/config and ad something like this...

Host foo.example.com
IdentityFile .ssh/id_rsa_foo.example.com

you can also do...

Host *.example.org
IdentityFile .ssh/id_rsa_example.org

Comment: That just adds to the target key to the end of the list, which won't solve the problem. `IdentitiesOnly` only with that will.